# Cryogenian Earth and biodiversity

Tags: paleoclimatology, evolution, precambrian, astrobiology

After the glaciations of the Cryogenian, Earth underwent a period of intense biodiversification which ultimately saw the emergence of the first animals of the succeeding Edicaran. What was it about the Cryogenian, or the alleviation of the icy conditions at the end of that period, that led to such evolution?

Comment: One hypothesis that I've read in multiple places is that the melting ice inundated the oceans with lots and lots and lots of nutrients. Until I can find a reference, I'm leaving this is a comment. The evolutionary progress had to be right for this to happen. Life hadn't evolved sufficiently before this to take advantage of previous ice age collapses.